# i need to break the line after a reach of 10 buttons

Tags: php

I need to break the line after a reach of 10 buttons.

Please be specific what are the code to be used for breaking the line.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require('connection.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbCandidates ");
if($result){
}     
echo "select Project to Reward for";       
$_SESSION['a']="project name-->";
echo "<body><form method='post' action='part1.php' ><input type='hidden' value='abhishek' name='aa'/>";
echo "<table><tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row["project_id"];     
    echo '<input type="radio" name="n1" value="';echo $row["project_id"]; echo '">';  echo"</input>";
    $_SESSION['b']=$row['candidate_name'];
    $_SESSION['c']=$row['candidate_position'];
    $_SESSION['c']=$row['candidate_nominee'];
    echo "</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table><input type='submit'/></form></body>";
```

Comment: Please clarify this code: if($result){    } no action performed in if condition

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because badly formatted code makes it harder to help. http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/

Comment: if($result) this is used to retrive the datas from the database in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean by BREAKING the line is creating another row for your table then try to use the following codes:

```html
<?php 
session_start();
require('connection.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbCandidates ");
if($result){
}     
echo "select Project to Reward for";       
$_SESSION['a']="project name-->";
echo "<body><form method='post' action='part1.php' ><input type='hidden' value='abhishek' name='aa'/>";
echo "<table>";
$counter = 0;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $counter++;
 if($counter==1){
  echo "<tr>";
 }
     echo "<td>";
     echo $row["project_id"];     
     echo '<input type="radio" name="n1" value="';echo $row["project_id"]; echo '">';  echo"</input>";
     $_SESSION['b']=$row['candidate_name'];
     $_SESSION['c']=$row['candidate_position'];
     $_SESSION['c']=$row['candidate_nominee'];
     echo "</td>";
 if($counter==10){
  echo "</tr>";
  $counter = 0;
 }
}
echo "</table><input type='submit'/></form></body>";
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: thank you it is working properly and i have a small issue that is how to display  $_SESSION['b']=$row['candidate_name'];
     $_SESSION['c']=$row['candidate_position'];
     $_SESSION['c']=$row['candidate_nominee']; these three lines in the next page by using the same break function